# Primality testing using cyclotomic polynomials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, cyclotomic-polynomials, primality-test

Can you prove or disprove the following claim:

> Let $\Phi_m(x)$ be the mth cyclotomic polynomial , and let $n$ be a natural number greater than one . If there exists an integer $a$ such that $$\Phi_{n-1}(a) \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$$ then $n$ is prime.

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzLszU2tOZKyy_SSLQ11MnP18lM0_DNT9EoyM9JrkzOydfI0zXUSdTUydO0tTXQKSjKzCvRUAJSualKmtZJRamJ2Zqa1gDluRVc&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==). I have verified this claim for all prime numbers less than $1000000$ .

Comment: You have to check the composites as well (In fact , it is sufficient to only check them for the claim) ! In the body, you only mention that you tested the primes ...

Comment: @Peter I also checked composites less than $50000$ with $a \le 100$ .

Comment: The converse anyway is clear. If $n$ is prime, then $x^{n-1}-1=\Phi_{n-1}(x)g(x)$ has $n-1$ roots $\bmod n$, and some of those must be roots of $\Phi_{n-1}(x)$. If $n$ is a Carmichael number, e.g., say $n=561$, then $\Phi_{560}(x)$ is a factor of $f(x)=x^{560}-1$, and $f$ has many roots $\bmod{561}$, and it's surprising to me that none of those are roots of $\Phi_{560}(x)\bmod{561}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from Dickson, History of the Theory of Numbers, Volume 1, page 378:

A. Hurwitz [L'intermediaire des math. 2 (1895) 41] gave a generalization of Proth's theorem. Let $F_n(x)$ denote an irreducible factor of degree $\phi(n)$ of $x^n-1$. Then if there exists an integer $q$ such that $F_{p-1}(q)$ is divisible by $p$, $p$ is a prime.

I haven't been able to find the Hurwitz paper.

Comment: So, I reinvented the wheel.

Comment: Be proud of discovering on your own a result first found by Hurwitz.